# Prevent hotlinking but allow specified images?

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I'm preventing hotlinking with this in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

However, I'd like to allow certain specified images to be hotlink-able, how do I do this?
I can't find anything about it online.

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^images/allow-hotlink/.+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, even specifying the actual file "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images/button\.gif$" but both methods didn't work. I tried lots of variations =(

Answer (score 0):

you can add another rewrite condition like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^whitelisted-directory/.*
```

but its more efficient and easier just to add one write rule that does nothing above and declare it at last like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(whitlistet-directory1|whitelisted-directory2) - [L]
```